# How to make my player move in air to right and left while jumping with pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a platformer game with pyqt5. I have coded the gravity, jump and moving functions. The problem is I can't move my player in air while it is jumping. I can move it while falling ( in the gravity function) but if the player is jumping and I try to move the player left or right the player teleports straight away to the original platform where it jumped at the first place.

Here is my code

## gravity:

```py
def painovoima(self):
        if (not self.jump and not self.tormays() and self.y < 880) or (not self.tormays() and self.y < 880 and self.oikea):
            painovoima = 0.25 * (-self.mass) * (self.nopeus ** 2)
            self.y = self.y - painovoima
            self.pelihahmo.setPos(self.x, self.y)
            print(self.y)
            if self.y >= 880:
                self.y = 880
                print("havisit pelin")
                #seuraavaks vois tulla joku teksti näytölle jos lukee, et hävis peli
            self.pelihahmo.setPos(self.x, self.y)
            if self.tormays():
                self.pelihahmo.setPos(self.x, self.y)
```

## jump:

```py
    def hyppy(self):
        #Ei toimi tääkää, joten koodataan uusiks

        if self.jump:
            y = self.pelihahmo.y()
            Force = self.mass * (self.hyppynopeus ** 2)
            y -= Force
            self.pelihahmo.setPos(self.x, y)
            self.hyppynopeus = self.hyppynopeus - 1
            if self.hyppynopeus < 0:
                self.mass = -1
            if self.hyppynopeus == -8:
                self.jump = False
                self.hyppynopeus = 8
                self.mass = 1
            if self.tormays() or self.y >= 880:
                self.jump = False
                self.hyppynopeus = 8
                self.mass = 1
```

## left:

```py
    def left(self):
        self.vasen = True
        if self.vasen or not self.tormays():
            self.update_x()
            self.x = self.x - self.nopeus
            if self.x < -1500:
                self.x = -1500
            self.pelihahmo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("player_object_left.png").scaled(30, 30, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))
            self.pelihahmo.setPos(self.x, self.y)
            self.vasen = False
            self.oikea = True
```

## right:

```py
    def right(self):
        self.oikea = True
        if self.oikea or not self.tormays():
            self.update_x()
            self.x = self.x + self.nopeus
            if self.x > 0:
                self.x = 0
            self.pelihahmo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("player_object_right.png").scaled(30, 30, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))
            self.pelihahmo.setPos(self.x, self.y)
            self.oikea = False
            self.vasen = True
```

Comment: first of all, i would like to say that you have a good bit of code. My question is, what is your question please ?   which part are you stuck on and what help do you need ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, the problem is, i can't move my player while it is in the air which leads to the problem that I cant actually jump on other platforms. I can only jump on the first platform.